# Why Type Check Error are not detected when Pattern Matching on Generic Type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, type-inference

Defining the following structure:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

and the following function (*please note that the second line which is the type check error spot is also an algorithmic mistake for short-circuiting the result, but nonetheless it came up and i wonder why type checking is not spotting it*)

```
    def foldRight[A, B] (list: List[A], z: B)(f: (A,B) => B ): B = list match {
        case Nil => z
        case Cons(0, _) => z // problematic line
        case Cons(s, xs) => f(s, foldRight(xs, z) (f))
    }
```

I know scala also suffer from Type Erasure, but i am surprised that in this case, this can't be detected at compilation time ? `Cons` is `Cons[A]` in this case, and `z` is clearly of type `B` ?

Any reason why such code actually compile ?

## EDIT1

Sounds like there is a lengthy explanation here https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b, but Long read. If someone could make it simpler :)

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here

Comment: For the same reason you can write `def foo(a: Any): Boolean = a match { case 0 => true; case _ => false }` Like it or not, **pattern matching** in Scala is quite flexible but unsafe. - In short, since pattern matching works in runtime, that case just says in case `A` turned out to be something whose the literal value `0` is equals to, then you can go for this route, otherwise not.

Comment: hummm i am not sure to follow you on this one ? Any is the ancestor of everything, so yes that should work. In this case, this is different no ?

Comment: No, after erasure `A` is juts **Any**. It would be interesting to see what would the compiler does if it would be impossible for `A` to be an **AnyVal**. - ha! The compiler is [smart enough](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/gCYvSYiYQ1G9F8pnONgKVQ/2)

Comment: Type-wise `A` is a type you know nothing about. And pattern matching allows you to _check_ if your value is matching some pattern - is equal to some value, is of some specified type - even if it knows nothing about the type (because checking if some assumption is correct is what pattern-matching does). It is a bad practice to abuse it, but it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3):

Why these or those decisions about language design were made is opinion based.

In Scala spec it's written:

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-parameter-inference-for-constructor-patterns

> 8.3.2 Type parameter inference for constructor patterns
>
> Assume a constructor pattern (1,…,) where class  has type
> parameters 1,…,. These type parameters are inferred in the same
> way as for the typed pattern (_: [1,…,]).

So for pattern `Cons(h, t)` type parameter `A` in `Cons[A](h, t)` is inferred as if the pattern were `_: Cons[A]` (which becomes `_: Cons[_]` at runtime because of erasure).

There is example there in the spec how types are inferred for

```
class Term[A]
class Number(val n: Int) extends Term[Int]
def f[B](t: Term[B]): B = t match {
  case y: Number => y.n
}
```

It's explained there why for the pattern `y: Number` type parameter `B` (**new** type parameter `B`) is inferred `Int`.

Similarly, in our case for the pattern `Cons(0, _)` (as if it were `_: Cons[A]`) `A` is inferred `Int`.

After `typer` phase (`scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xprint:typer", "-Xprint-types")`) the code becomes

```
def foldRight[A, B](list: App.List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = list{App.List[A]} match {
  case App.this{App.type}.Nil{App.Nil.type} => z{B}
  case (head: A, tail: App.List[A]): App.Cons[?A1](0{Int(0)}, _{App.List[A]}){App.Cons[?A1]} => z{B}
  case (head: A, tail: App.List[A]): App.Cons[?A2]((s @ _{A}){A}, (xs @ _{App.List[A]}){App.List[A]}){App.Cons[?A2]} => f.apply{(v1: A, v2: B): B}(s{A}, App.this{App.type}.foldRight{[A, B](list: App.List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B}[A, B]{(list: App.List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B}(xs{App.List[A]}, z{B}){(f: (A, B) => B): B}(f{(A, B) => B}){B}){B}
}{B}
```

and after `erasure` (`scalacOptions += "-Xprint:erasure"`) it becomes

```
def foldRight(list: App$List, z: Object, f: Function2): Object = {
  <synthetic> var rc9: Boolean = false;
  <synthetic> <stable> var x2: App$Cons = (null: App$Cons);
  {
    case <synthetic> val x1: App$List = list;
    case11(){
      if (App$Nil.==(x1))
        matchEnd10(z)
      else
        case12()
    };
    case12(){
      if (x1.$isInstanceOf[App$Cons]())
        {
          rc9 = true;
          x2 = (x1.$asInstanceOf[App$Cons](): App$Cons);
          {
            <synthetic> val p3: Object = x2.head();
            if (scala.Int.box(0).==(p3))
              matchEnd10(z)
            else
              case13()
          }
        }
      else
        case13()
    };
    case13(){
      if (rc9)
        {
          val s: Object = x2.head();
          val xs: App$List = x2.tail();
          matchEnd10(f.apply(s, App.this.foldRight(xs, z, f)))
        }
      else
        case14()
    };
    case14(){
      matchEnd10(throw new MatchError(x1))
    };
    matchEnd10(x: Object){
      x
    }
  }
};
```

Actually, code similar to yours compiles even in Haskell if we add the information that a type parameter `a` belongs to type classes `Eq` and `Num` to the context of function signature

https://ideone.com/qqOsI2

```hs
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
 
foldRight :: (Eq a, Num a) => List a -> b -> (a -> b -> b) -> b
foldRight list z f = case list of
  Nil -> z
  Cons 0 _ -> z
  Cons s xs -> f s (foldRight xs z f)
```

Type classes are not first-class citizens in Scala. So Scala can't request similar thing about something like `Num` (in Scala everything can be compared with `==`, so `Eq` is "automatical").

Comment: I need to dig a little. Thanks for the detail as always.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Since you mentioned well-known blog post "Ways to pattern match generic types in Scala" maybe you can also be interested in https://lptk.github.io/programming/2018/12/12/scala-pattern-warts-improvements.html

Answer (score 0):

> `Cons` is `Cons[A]` in this case

This is not correct, or at very least it is confusing. There are two types `A` here: the type parameter in `Cons[A]` and the type parameter in `foldRight[A,B]`. There is nothing to say that they are the same type. You could equally well define

```
case class Cons[Z](head: Z, tail: List[Z]) extends List[Z]
```

So on the problematic line

```
case Cons(0, _) => z // problematic line
```

the compiler treats this as `Cons[Int](0, _)` because the type of `head` is `Int`. The compiler is promiscuous in this case and allows this `match` in all cases even though it can only succeed if `foldLeft` is called with a `List[Int]`.

Comment: Disagree with the two type comments. The data type is defined and that is one thing and yes it separate from the fold right definition. The issue here is purely related to foldright where fix the A. And that is where the problem is. We fix A and pattern matching allows me to match Bologne types, and that’s not right .... but I understand it is a limitation of the language